# Create a back bar button programmatically

Tags: ios, ios7, backbarbuttonitem

I'm trying to create a back bar button programmatically, similar to the iOS 7 default back button. But when I add my back bar button to the navigation item. The Chevron plus is missing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [for backbutton in navigationbar ios ][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title/22603128#22603128

Comment: you can even try http://stackoverflow.com/a/16786531/2365064

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIImage* image_back = [UIImage imageNamed:@"leftarrow.png"];
    CGRect backframe = CGRectMake(15, 5, 15,21);
    UIButton *backbutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:backframe];
    [backbutton setBackgroundImage:image_back forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(Btn_back:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backbutton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    UIBarButtonItem *backbarbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backbutton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backbarbutton;
    [backbutton release];
-(IBAction)Btn_back:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```